# Using the Graph API to update the user "relationship_status"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbjs

Is it possible to change the logged in user's profile data at all with certain permissions. IE: if his relationship_status is married could we change it to single via the Graph APi, or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, you can't. That would be very unwise move from Facebook, if they allow such feature!